# Find the values of a and b such that $\binom{2n}{2} = a\binom{n}{2} + b(n^2)$

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus, binomial-coefficients

Find the values of a and b such that
$\binom{2n}{2} = a\binom{n}{2} + b(n^2)$

Comment: Just expand these out and solve two equations for the coefficients of $n$ and $n^2$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming the question is from a course on combinatorics, we can do the following way:

The LHS is the number of ways we can pick $2$ objects out of $2n$ objects.

Now, let us try to get the RHS: We have two terms, one is a combinatorial term (with just $n$ instead of $2n$ in the term), the other seems to be more an algebraic term. So, let us divide our $2n$ objects into two classes $A$ and $B$. We can pick $2$ objects out of $2n$ objects in two ways: either both objects come from same class, or both objects come from different classes. The first part (which is both come from same class) is $2 \times {n \choose 2}$, and the second part (which is they come from different classes) is $n \times n$. So, the LHS can be equated to $2{n \choose 2} + n^2$. Equating the like terms, we  have $a=2, b=1$.

If we go the algebraic way, it is not evident if the solution is unique (unless we solve it completely). Similarly, I am not sure if there are other combinatorial arguments which can lead to different values of $a$ and $b$.

Answer (score 1):

The question is quite simple, convert the binomial coefficients to a more readily solvable form first.
$\binom{2n}{2}=\frac{2n(2n-1)}{2}=n(2n-1)$. Similarly, $\binom{n}{2}=\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$.
Your equation therefore simplifies to: $n(2n-1)=\frac{an(n-1)}{2}+bn^2$

Equating coefficients and solving simultaneously should allow you to derive the answer.

Comment: ok thanks...totally understood

Comment: @Sherlock Holmes  how do you solve the 2 parameter quadratic. I have been making a mere of it for  half an hour now :/ Or is there an easier approach? $bn^2+a\frac{n(n-1)}{2}-n(2n-1)=0$

Comment: Well Nic, we simply equate coefficients. Doing so yields

$\frac{a}{2}+b=2$, and $\frac{-a}{2}=-1$. 

It follows that $a=2$, and by substituting into the first equation, that $b=1$